# Is there a way to make Azure SQL Database report a newer version number?

Tags: azure-sql-database

We are trying to get Moodle installed in Azure, and the most cost-effective way to do this for our purposes is to use Azure SQL database.

Azure SQL database is always running the latest stable build of SQL Server, but reports a version number beginning with 12.* - this causes Moodle to complain about the database version as it wants something 2017 or newer.

Is there any way to have Azure SQL Database fudge the version number it reports so that the application thinks it's more modern?

Answer (score 0):

Contact Moodley and ask if their software is compatible with Azure SQL Database.

Even if there was a way to fool and bypass the installation I would not go with that pattern.